# How to represent just 'time' with JodaTime

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime

I'm not sure how can I explain just 'time', so I wanna start with an example.
When I write a movie player, I want to represent the start time(00:00:00) in millis as 0, and if current frame position is on 5 minutes(00:05:00), it would be 300,000(5 * 60 * 1000).
I don't care about timezone, calendar or clock information in real world.

However, JodaTime, for example, `Instant` is related to Unixtime(based on 1970), `Interval`, `Duration` and `Period` are based on `Instant`, and `LocalTime` is based on 24-hour(which enforce hour field to 1-24).

Of course, I can parse "00:05:00" into 300,000 manually, but I wonder how can I achieve this goal with JodaTime or other library.

Comment: Are you sure `Duration` is not what you want? I'm not sure about JodaTime, but the Java Time `Duration` (based off of JodaTime) represents just that—a duration of time.

Comment: A duration is the length of a time span, which exactly describes the concept you mentioned. I agree with Slaw, as I don't see why `Duration` does not fit your needs.

Comment: By the way, if you can, you should use the newer Java Date And Time API, available in the `java.time` package, instead of Joda Time. The latter is in maintenance mode, and their very own website suggests in the *About* section to move to `java.time`.

Comment: @Slaw I think `Duration` is millis holder. It's right it has no *clock information*, but `Duration` needs millis to instantiate. Otherwise, it provides `parse` method, but it requires specific formatted string. There is no way to convert custom formatted string(eg. 00:05:00) into millis or `Duration`. Formatting `Duration` into string is not also available.

Comment: @MC Emperor I'll check `java.time` packages, but sadly in Android, it requires API level 26 (Android 8.0). It's too early to use to support many Android devices.

Comment: Regarding Android support of `java.time` pre Java 8: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `Duration`

Your statement about the [`Duration`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) class is incorrect. You said it is based on `Instant`, but, no, it is not.

A `Duration` represents a span of time *not* attached to the timeline. A `Duration` in *Joda-Time* is merely a count of milliseconds. This fact is stated in its Javadoc.

Ditto for `Period`, which represents a span-of-time unattached to the timeline on a scale of years-months-days. A `Duration` works on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

To represent a span of five minutes:

```
Duration d = Duration.standardMinutes( 5 ) ;
```

If you want to get the moment in the future by that amount of time, add that duration to the current moment.

```
Instant fiveMinutesInFuture =  new Instant().plus( d ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

To represent a duration as text, use the standard ISO 8601 format, with a `P` at the beginning and a `T` separating the years-months-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion.

So five minutes is `PT5M`.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

Parse such ISO 8601 strings.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT5M" ) ;  // Five minutes.
```

### Clock format

For serializing a `duration` object as text, always use the ISO 8601 standard format, never clock format.

For user-interface presentation, I suggest you not represent a span of time using clock notation such as `00:05:00`. Doing so is confusing and ambiguous to users. Use the ISO 8601 standard formats instead, as they are designed to be practical and unambiguous.

If you insist on representing the duration in clock time format, call the `getStandard…` methods to get the hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
String output = 
        String.format( "%02d", d.getStandardHours() ) + 
        ":" +
        String.format( "%02d", d.getStandardMinutes() ) +
        ":" +
        String.format( "%02d", d.getStandardSeconds() ) 
;
```

> 00:05:00

If the duration might be over 24 hours long, you will also need to call `getStandardDays`. These days are merely chunks of time of 24-hours long. Such days are *not* calendar days as the `Duration` is not attached to the timeline.

## *java.time*

Be aware that Joda-Time is now in maintenance mode. It’s successor, *java.time*, is built into Java 8 and later as well as Android 26+. For Java 6 & 7 use *ThreeTen-Backport*. For earlier Android, use *ThreeTenABP*.

The concepts are the same in *java.time* as discussed here. The `java.time.Duration` class is quite similar except for the much finer resolution of nanoseconds and a slightly different syntax.

```
Instant.now().plus(
    Duration.ofMinutes( 5 )
)
```

Or:

```
Instant.now().plus(
    Duration.parse( "PT5M" )
)
```

To build a clock-reading, call the `to…Part` methods.

```
String output = 
        String.format( "%02d", d.toHoursPart() ) + 
        ":" +
        String.format( "%02d", d.toMinutesPart() ) +
        ":" +
        String.format( "%02d", d.toSecondsPart() ) 
;
```

> 00:05:00

Comment: I agree my statement is wrong, but I commented above, I cannot find a way to use with formatted strings. Is there any way to convert custom formatted string into `Duration` or vice versa?

Comment: @khcpietro Your Question does not ask about parsing but for a mere mention at the end.

Comment: "Never represent a span of time using clock notation such as 00:05:00. Doing so is confusing and ambiguous, and a bad practice". Are you saying don't _persist_ or _transport_ in clock notation? Because timers and stopwatches display durations in that format all the time. Though to be fair, that's simply the presentation (i.e. formatting, not parsing).

Comment: @Slaw Perhaps. Though I remember in the days of early digital watches, many people confused the stopwatch/timer features for the time-of-day. Do as you see fit. I suggest presenting durations to users in ISO 8601 format, perhaps adding a SPACE between letters. The training for users would be minimal.

Comment: I guess I've just never seen a duration presented in ISO 8601 format outside of more technical contexts. For instance, every oven and microwave I've seen uses clock notation for timers. Timer/stopwatch apps on my phone use clock notation. Those handheld stopwatches you often see at athletic events use clock notation. My running watch uses clock notation. Sports use clock notation to show how much time is left in the game/half/quarter/period/what-have-you.

Comment: @Slaw I added a section showing how to generate clock text.